# Value of specific date in date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

At the start of the problem, you only have 2 columns, date and value.

From here the idea is getting the value from past month and past year. The final output would be something like this:

| date | value | m1 | m12 | m1_val | m12_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-27 | 100 | 2022-01-27 | 2021-02-27 | nan | nan |
| 2022-03-27 | 300 | 2022-02-27 | 2021-03-27 | 100 | nan |
| 2022-03-30 | 500 | 2022-02-30 | 2022-03-30 | nan | nan |
| 2023-02-27 | 800 | 2023-01-27 | 2022-02-27 | nan | 100 |

I have already done it but without vectorization, and I wanted to change the final apply function for something vectorize, to not need to go row by row.

For example, to create the columns m1 and m12 you could use

```
d['year'] = d['date'].dt.year
d['month'] = d['date'].dt.month
d['day'] = d['date'].dt.day
d['month-1'] = (d['month'] - 1)
d['year-1'] = d['date'].dt.year
d['year-12'] = d['year'] - 1
d.loc[d['month-1'] == 0, 'year-1'] = d.loc[d['month-1'] == 0, 'year-1'] - 1
d.loc[d['month-1'] == 0, 'month-1'] = 12
d['m1'] = pd.to_datetime(d[['year-1', 'month-1', 'day']].rename({'year-1':'year', 'month-1':'month'}, axis=1), errors='coerce')
d['m12'] = pd.to_datetime(d[['year-12', 'month', 'day']].rename({'year-12':'year'}, axis=1), errors='coerce')
d = d.drop(['year', 'month', 'day', 'month-1', 'year-1', 'year-12'], axis=1)
```

And with this, I was using the next apply function to fill the cols m1_val and m12_val, which basically search each needed value in the date column and return it.

```py
def test(x, col):
    value = d.loc[d['date'] == x[col]]['value']
    if len(value) == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return value.iloc[0]

d['m1_val'] = d.apply(lambda x: test(x, 'm1'), axis=1)
d['m12_val'] = d.apply(lambda x: test(x, 'm12'), axis=1)
```

But, is there a better way to get the value of m1 from date column without using for loops? I was thinking maybe I could use something with np.where o d.loc... but I didn't know how, with `d.loc[d['date'].isin(d['m1'])]` and then a groupby()? But in terms of performance it looks similar as using apply()

Comment: you might want to have a look at [pandas date offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html)

Comment: I tried with it, but the problem are the days that doesn't exist, for example `d.index - pd.DateOffset(months=1)` for 2022-03-30 would return 2022-02-28 which doesn't work in my case, since the days that doesn't exist I want them empty, not the nearest existing date

Comment: so you basically just want to *replace* the month number and if that date doesn't exist, you want to discard the value? I find that hard to understand *why*; what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?`

Comment: Basically getting a table where I have the data of current month, previous month and 12 months ago, and show those value to business. And they prefer to keep it in daily data instead of monthly to be able to draw some plots in DataStudio. But using dateoffset creates a problem when the previous month has more days, like for example jan & feb, in which you will get the 28 days from feb, but only 28 for january. And therefore if later you sum those value you will not have all the values from january.

Comment: that's why we love the business people. ok so but if your logic decides to *not define* a start date (because reasons described above), you cannot do any calculations or plot, no?

Comment: mmm not following. you would get a table with columns date, value, date - 1, date - 12, value - 1, value - 12, with daily data. Then you can plot date with value, date - 1 with value - 1, date -12 with value - 12. The start date of the dataset would be 2019 because GDPR doesn't let you save more than 36 months of some things. But don't worry I'll use the apply method, that at the end all these are calculations that I do at 2am in the morning, so no one really cares how much it takes xD